# How to pass a value in a form OnPost method React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```
    const afterSubmission = (e, message) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(message);
        if (message === "") return
        displayMessage(message)
        
        messageInput.value=""
        }




<div id="message-container"></div>
                <form onSubmit = {afterSubmission}>
                    <label for="message-input">Message</label>
                    <input type="text" id="message-input" />
                    <button type="submit" id="send-button">Send</button>
                </form>
```

I have these two pieces of code, my question is how can I pass the value from the input tag in the form to the afterSubmission method?

Comment: I would recommend you go through some tutorials like https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/javascript/how-to-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is the same component, an easy solution would be to use `state`.

Your code snippets aren't very useful, just as an FYI for future questions, but here's an example of me tracking form state.

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("test");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setMessage((old) => e.target.value);
  };

  const afterSubmission = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(message);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={afterSubmission}>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="message-input"
          value={message}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <button 
          type="submit" 
          id="send-button"
        >
          Send
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As you can see, this tracks your message in the component's state which makes it accessible in the `afterSubmission` function.